# How do I bookmark a comment for my own reading later?

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat

Throughout the stack exchange sites, often times it happens with me that I find a particularly engaging discussion on a topic, but can't read it immediately due to lack of time or whatever.

When I later try to find that discussion, I cannot at times. It's frustrating.

I'm aware of the **star symbol** under questions which lets me bookmark it. But if I have to find a particular comment, I still have to scroll down a lot to find it. It's a real pain in the a**.

I'm not looking to **permalink** a discussion to share it somewhere else. I just want to be able to bookmark it for my own reading...later.

How can I do this? Is there a browser plugin or such that'll let me do this?

Comment: Bookmark the permalink, no?

Answer (score 3):

Behind each comment, there is a timestamp. That timestamp is a link that takes you to exactly that comment.
Depending on your OS and browser, right-clicking the timestamp should give you a menu where you can copy the link to the comment, and/or add it to your browser bookmarks.
For example, Oded's comment below your post is:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292083/how-do-i-bookmark-a-comment-for-my-own-reading-later#comment948689_292083
```

You can actually leave out the title of the question; the following link to the same comment will automatically expand:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292083/#comment948689_292083
```

As has been pointed out by others, comments are volatile. They are second-class citizens and prone to deletion. If you want to be sure that you can read the conversation later, expand it and save the page locally.

Answer (score 0):

Comments on stackexchange are second class citizen they are prone to be deleted unless upvoted and useful, if someone have answered your question or query please ask them to write an answer for good, you cannot bookmark chat on SE for now.